# SQL Parsing Strings

Tags: sql, sql-server

Our Production Notes table and our Dev Notes table are now different.

In Production - System notes were being added into the column "The_Notes" and were identified living between two hash tags, i.e. "# system note blah, blah #".

Users want the System Notes in a different column from what they enter as user notes.

You know where this is going....

I have a stored procedure which runs on a daily job and each night it truncates the Dev tables and inserts what is in the Production tables.

I need a query that splits out the System notes from our Production table and inserts them into their own column.

Example of Production Table

Production Notes Table Columns & Row Samples

```
|Num | The_Notes
| 0  | Called 
| 1  | # Claim created Dec 1, 2016 # # Need By Date Dec 24, 2016 # I Filed
| 2  | Call me 
| 3  | # Claim created Dec 1, 2016 # Call me back
| 4  | # Claim created Dec 1, 2016 # # Need By Date Dec 24, 2016 #
```

Not all rows have system notes.  Not all rows have user notes.

In C# this is a breeze for me, SQL is not my primary language, our SQL guy bailed.

Dev Table Results Should Be:

```
|Num | System_Notes                                                  |User Notes
| 0  |                                                               | Called 
| 1  | # Claim created Dec 1, 2016 # # Need By Date Dec 24, 2016 #   |I Filed
| 2  |                                                               |Call me
| 3  | # Claim created Dec 1, 2016 #                                 |Call me 
| 4  | # Claim created Dec 1, 2016 # # Need By Date Dec 24, 2016 #
```

I was hoping to do this by counting the # tags to see if they were even number and doing an if substring and replace

Comment: This is really bad design... If  - by any chance - this can be changed, you should maintain a `Notes`-Table with a `NoteType` column marking the note as `system` or `user`. It is against 1NF to combine multiple values in one column...

Comment: Thanks, yes I agree it was a horrible design!!

Comment: If it is breeze in C#, lets read in C# and parse. Design is totally wrong, and SQL doesn't use any methods to optimise, must read all data with "brutal force"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below query

```
select num, 
       case 
         when charindex('#', notes) > 0 
           then reverse(SUBSTRING(reverse(notes), CHARINDEX('#', reverse(notes)), len(notes))) 
         else '' 
       end system_notes,
       case 
         when charindex('#', notes) > 0 
           then reverse(SUBSTRING(reverse(notes), 0, CHARINDEX('#', reverse(notes)))) 
         else notes 
       end User_notes
   from table1;
```

The above query returning below result

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A good way of counting the number of #'s would be to use the code below:

```
len(the_notes) - len(replace(the_notes, '#', ''))
```

From there you can get everything after the last occurrence of the # for user notes by using

```
select reverse(substring(reverse(the_notes),0,CHARINDEX('#',reverse(the_notes))))
```

The the data for system notes can then be extracted with

```
select left(the_notes,LEN(the_notes) - CHARINDEX('#', REVERSE(the_notes)))
```

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in my comment, you should really try to store your values in a `1:n`-related side table. The following code shows an approach to get all the parts neatly separated.

I suggest to replace the signs the way, that you get XML back:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(Num INT, The_Notes VARCHAR(500));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
 (0,'Called') 
,(1,'# Claim created Dec 1, 2016 # # Need By Date Dec 24, 2016 # I Filed')
,(2,'Call me ')
,(3,'# Claim created Dec 1, 2016 # Call me back')
,(4,'# Claim created Dec 1, 2016 # # Need By Date Dec 24, 2016 #');


WITH GetRidOfForbiddenCharacters AS
(
    SELECT Num
          ,(SELECT The_Notes AS [*] FOR XML PATH('')) AS The_Notes
    FROM @tbl
)
,CleanTheStart AS
(
    SELECT Num
          ,CASE WHEN LEFT(The_Notes,2)='# ' THEN STUFF(The_Notes,1,2,'<x>') ELSE The_Notes END AS The_Notes
    FROM GetRidOfForbiddenCharacters
)
,CleanTheEnd AS
(
    SELECT Num
          ,CASE WHEN RIGHT(The_Notes,2)=' #' THEN LEFT(The_Notes,LEN(The_Notes)-2) + '</x>' ELSE The_Notes END AS The_Notes
    FROM CleanTheStart
)
,Replaced AS
(
    SELECT Num
          ,CAST('<root>' + REPLACE(REPLACE(LTRIM(RTRIM(The_Notes)),' # # ','</x><x>'),' # ','</x>') + '</root>' AS XML) AS The_Notes_XML
    FROM CleanTheEnd
)
SELECT Num
      ,x.value('.','nvarchar(max)') AS SystemNote
      ,x.value('(/root/text())[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS UserNote
FROM Replaced
OUTER APPLY The_Notes_XML.nodes('/root/x') AS A(x)
```

This is one example of a resulting XML

```
<root>
  <x>Claim created Dec 1, 2016</x>
  <x>Need By Date Dec 24, 2016</x>
I Filed
</root>
```

And this is the full result

```
+---+---------------------------+-------------------+
| 0 | NULL                      | Called            |
+---+---------------------------+-------------------+
| 1 | Claim created Dec 1, 2016 | I Filed           |
+---+---------------------------+-------------------+
| 1 | Need By Date Dec 24, 2016 | I Filed           |
+---+---------------------------+-------------------+
| 2 | NULL                      | Call me           |
+---+---------------------------+-------------------+
| 3 | Claim created Dec 1, 2016 | Call me back      |
+---+---------------------------+-------------------+
| 4 | Claim created Dec 1, 2016 | NULL              |
+---+---------------------------+-------------------+
| 4 | Need By Date Dec 24, 2016 | NULL              |
+---+---------------------------+-------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the version of SQL Server you are running as I have a suspicion that I read somewhere that 2016 supports the SPLIT command (or similar).  However if you want it to work on earlier versions too, you can create your own function to split the string up.  Something like this;

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[splitString] (@String VARCHAR(MAX), @delimiter CHAR)

RETURNS @SplitValues TABLE
(
    Asset_ID VARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL
)

AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @FoundIndex INT
DECLARE @ReturnValue VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @FoundIndex = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @String)

WHILE (@FoundIndex <> 0)
BEGIN
  SET @ReturnValue = SUBSTRING(@String, 0, @FoundIndex)
  INSERT @SplitValues (Asset_ID) VALUES (@ReturnValue)
  SET @String = SUBSTRING(@String, @FoundIndex + 1, len(@String) - @FoundIndex)
  SET @FoundIndex = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @String)
END

INSERT @SplitValues (Asset_ID) VALUES (@String)

RETURN

END
```

This doesn't do quite what you are asking as it accepts two strings, the first being the source string and the second being the character to look for (in your case a #) and returns multiple rows but I'm sure it could be repurposed to split it into columns instead.

Comment: I think you'll find this interesting https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings

Answer (score 0):

```
select  num
       ,left(the_notes,len(the_notes)-charindex('#',reverse('#'+the_notes))+1)  as system_notes
       ,ltrim(right('#'+the_notes,charindex('#',reverse('#'+the_notes))-1))     as user_notes

from    t
;
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is a bit more lengthier than it needs to be, but here it is anyway:

```
DECLARE @T AS TABLE (
    Num INT,
    The_Notes VARCHAR(1024)
)

INSERT @T VALUES
(0, 'Called'),
(1, '# Claim created Dec 1, 2016 # # Need By Date Dec 24, 2016 # I Filed'),
(2, 'Call me'),
(3, '# Claim created Dec 1, 2016 # Call me back'),
(4, '# Claim created Dec 1, 2016 # # Need By Date Dec 24, 2016 #'),
(6, '# Claim created Dec 1, 2016 # # Need By Date Dec 24, 2016'),
(7, '# Claim created Dec 1, 2016 # Need By Date Dec 24, 2016 #')

;
WITH A AS (
    SELECT 1 R, *, CHARINDEX('#', The_Notes, I1 + 1) I2, CAST('' AS VARCHAR(MAX)) SN FROM (
        SELECT Num, The_Notes, CHARINDEX('#', The_Notes) I1
        FROM (
            SELECT Num, CAST(The_Notes AS VARCHAR(MAX)) The_Notes FROM @T
        ) T
    ) T
    UNION ALL
    SELECT R + 1 R, Num, The_Notes, I3, I4, SN FROM (
        SELECT *, CHARINDEX('#', The_Notes, I3 + 1) I4 FROM (
            SELECT *, CHARINDEX('#', The_Notes) I3 FROM (
                SELECT R, Num
                    , CAST(STUFF(The_Notes, I1, I2 - I1 + 1, '') AS VARCHAR(MAX)) The_Notes
                    , CAST(CONCAT(SN, SUBSTRING(The_Notes, I1, I2 - I1 + 1), ' ') AS VARCHAR(MAX)) SN
                FROM A
                WHERE I2 <> 0
            ) T
        ) T
    ) T
)
SELECT Num, RTRIM(SN) SystemNotes, LTRIM(The_Notes) UserNotes FROM (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Num ORDER BY R DESC) O FROM A
) T
WHERE O = 1
ORDER BY Num
```